# What is the Product of Fourier Coefficients?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f, g$ be continuous $1$-periodic functions. Show that $$\widehat{fg}(n)=\sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}}\hat{f}(n-m)\hat{g}(m).$$

Here the $\widehat{f\cdot g}$ denotes the Fourier coefficient of $f\cdot g$, and $\hat{f}$ and $\hat{g}$ the Fourier coefficients of $f$ and $g$, respectively.

I am able to show that the sum converges (via Cauchy-Schwarz). But I am having trouble showing equality. Does anyone have a hint to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hint: the Fourier decomposition is a sum of orthogonal functions.

Comment: Could please you elaborate just a little more?

Comment: Write down the definition of the Fourier transform.

Comment: Oh, someone edited my post. I was trying to denote the Fourier coefficients.